# Include external JavaScript file in Node-Gulp-Webpack build

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webpack, commonjs

I have an app built with Node-Gulp-Webpack.

I have an external JavaScript file `external.js` that is not local to my app, but I want to be able to `require` it in my app. This file is on a path for which there is an environment variable named `MY_PATH`.

How can I include this `external.js` as-is in my build without making a Node module out of it?

So far, this does not work and doesn't return a useful error message:

```
var external = require(process.env.MY_PATH + '/external.js');
```

Comment: Are you `require`'ing this external file into a client side file, or in your nodejs app?

Comment: Is `process.env.MY_PATH` being resolved correctly? What is the output of `console.log(process.env.MY_PATH)`?

Comment: I created a env variable called MY_PATH set to a path and used `require(process.env.MY_PATH)` and it worked using the node REPL, it didn't work at first because I had to open a new cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gulp-remote-src](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-remote-src), the example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var remoteSrc = require('gulp-remote-src');

gulp.task('remote', function() { 
    remoteSrc(['app.js', 'jquery.js'], {
        base: 'http://myapps.com/assets/',
    })
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
})
```